# When do you have to close a php mysqli stmt before preparing a new one?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

If I do not close the stmt at the end of this code snippet:

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT typeId FROM types WHERE name = 'author'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($typeId);
    $stmt->fetch();
```

(with this:)

```
    $stmt->close();
```

Then the following prepared statement fails with error code 0 and no error:

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO typeTracker (reserved_id, typeId) VALUES (NULL, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $typeId);
```

Why? Is it because I called the bind_result and fetch functions in the first block of code? I don't typically have to close statements before preparing new ones.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If `$stmt` gets replaced or falls out of scope it gets destroyed. You can close it as a formality, but normally it gets taken care of anyway.

Calling `close()` frees up any associated resources immediately. If you don't do that you'll need to wait for the garbage collector to take care of it.

Comment: The two blocks of code were literally right as you see them, though. I don't see how `$stmt` could have fallen out of scope or gotten destroyed? Thanks for the answer, though!

Comment: If that script finishes, it goes out of scope. If that variable gets replaced with another statement it goes out of scope. In both cases it gets automatically destroyed.

Comment: Both blocks of code were within the same script. One right above the other, as shown in the example. And the `$stmt` variable was never replaced with another statement.

Comment: Basically, if I don't explicitly close the statement variable before reusing it to prepare the second prepared statement below... I get an error saying bind_param cannot work with a boolean (aka `$stmt` = false)

Comment: When you say `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(...)` the second time you're not "reusing it", you're assigning a brand new value to `$stmt` and the old is thrown into the garbage. If you're getting an error that's a sign you should [enable exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) to make tracking down errors easier. It's possible that the MySQL connection is in the middle of something and `close()` flushes that operation, freeing up the connection for use.

Comment: Each connection has an internal state and can only do one thing at a time. If you don't completely fetch all the results it's stuck in "deliver results" mode and can't prepare queries. `fetch_all()` can clear that up by grabbing everything at once. Normally it's counter-productive to `fetch()` individual entries *unless* you're fetching more data than can fit in memory and need to stream results.